# Download files with Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is there a way to download media files directly from the Chrome browser? In the stock Android browser I can long-click a link and select "Save link" to accomplish that, but Chrome doesn't offer that option and opens a media player instead.

Answer (score 12):

In Chrome, keep your finger pressed on the link, and you will see an option "Save Link".
Hence, the file(s) will be saved in the Downloads folder.

To access it and (perhaps) other folders in the future, I recommend downloading a File Management app.

The best ones are said to be [ES File Manager](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd/%22ES%20File%20Manager%22) and [ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tZXRhZ28uYXN0cm8iXQ../).

While generally, ASTRO is said to be better, the free version has ads.

Your choice!

Comment: The option 'Save link' doesn't appear in the context menu.

Comment: Solution found [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53870/5962).

Answer (score 8):

Click on the link and close that tab or go back once it tries to play that media.  Go to your chrome history from the menu and long press the link and save it.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! +1

Answer (score 2):

Chrome on Android has the "save link" now when long pressing on files (such as media) which when just pressed regularly play the content.

the funny thing was that I thought save link would have copied the url or created a bookmark, not download the file...so your question text helped me :)

Answer (score -1):

Download an app named [Turbo Download Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.okythoos.android.tdmpro).

With one click on the file in Chrome, the option comes for this app. Thus, it downloads the files required.